# Align two dives vertical on top of each other

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, styled-components

I am trying to place to flex items on top of each other but not overlap and stay together until hit another break point.

I am using tailwind with styled components its the first time i am using both and struggling.

At the moment i have a div with an image that i want to place just above a div with description. The problem i am having there is a big gap between the two. The parent is using `flex` and `flex-direction: column` I though that if i add a flex: 1 to the children it will stick the two together.

Another thing is that i am inserting the image straight into the div its self and forces me to use `height: 100vh;` which could be a problem but thats the only way i can actually see the image

```
    export const CardContainer = styled.div`
      ${tw`
        flex
        flex-col
        justify-center
        items-center
        h-full
      `}
    
      @media (min-width: 800px) {
        flex-direction: row;
        height: 100vh;
        padding: 200px 30px;
      }
    `;

    export const CardImage = styled.div`
      ${tw`
        w-10/12
        overflow-hidden
        mt-20
        rounded-t-lg
      `}
    
      background-image: url("../../../images/image-product-mobile.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100%;
      height: 50vh;
    
      @media (min-width: 800px) {
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 0px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5rem;
        border-top-left-radius: 0.5rem;
        border-top-right-radius: 0rem;
        min-height: 100vh;
        min-width: 100%;
        background-image: url("../../../images/image-product-desktop.jpg");
      }
    `;
export const CardDescriptionContainer = styled.div`
  ${tw`
    w-10/12
    bg-white
    rounded-b-lg
    p-5
  `}

  @media (min-width: 800px) {
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.5rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 0rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 50vh;
  }
`;
```

ProductCard component:

```
export const ProductCard = () => {
  return (
    <CardContainer>
      <CardImage></CardImage>
      <CardDescriptionContainer>
      </CardDescriptionContainer>
    </CardContainer>
  );
};
```

This is what i am stuck with:

[image]

This is what i am trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
display:flex;
align-items:flex-start;
justify-content:center;
flex-direction:column;
```